# GL/glew.h: No such file or directory in glew.c

Tags: c++, cmake, glew

When I try to compile my program I get this error

```
C:\...\CLionProjects\Radix\vendors\glew-2.1.0\src\glew.c:34:10: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GL/glew.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

The error is in the library code, what am I doing wrong here?

My project structure looks like this:

```
Radix
|- Radix-core
   |- cpp code..
|- vendors
   |- CMakeLists.txt
   |- glew-2.1.0
   |- Other libs..
- CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt (Just glew parts)

```
add_subdirectory(vendors)

add_definitions(-DTW_STATIC -DTW_NO_LIB_PRAGMA -DTW_NO_DIRECT3D -DGLEW_STATIC -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)

# Including GLEW
include_directories(vendors/glew-2.1.0/include)
set(ALL_LIBS opengl32 glfw GLEW_210)

target_link_libraries(Radix ${ALL_LIBS})
```

vendors/CMakeLists.txt (Just glew parts)

```
add_definitions(-DTW_STATIC -DTW_NO_LIB_PRAGMA -DTW_NO_DIRECT3D -DGLEW_STATIC -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)

### GLEW ###
set(GLEW_HEADERS)
set(GLEW_SOURCE glew-2.1.0/src/glew.c)
set(GLEW_INCLUDE glew-2.1.0/include)

add_library(GLEW_210 ${GLEW_SOURCE} ${GLEW_INCLUDE})
target_link_libraries(GLEW_210 ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${EXTRA_LIBS})
```

Comment: And GL/glew.h is under vendors/glew-2.1.0/include ?

Comment: Yes, GL/glew.h is in vendors/glew-2.1.0/include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding your include directory to the source files for GLEW_210 does nothing. Add it as a PUBLIC include directory instead, so the compilation of `glew.c` also has access to glew headers:

```
target_include_directories(GLEW_210 PUBLIC glew-2.1.0/include)
```

This also propagates the include directory to any targets that link with GLEW_210, so you can then drop the `include_directories` statement in your main CMakeLists.txt